# Upgrading scipy on Mac OS Mavericks 10.9.2

Tags: python, scipy, installation, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to upgrade the scipy (currently I have version '0.11.0') on my machine, but I'm getting some compiler error that I can not work around:

When I invoke:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade scipy
```

I get:

```
cc: scipy/optimize/Zeros/bisect.c

clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
error: Command "cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include -c scipy/optimize/Zeros/bisect.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/scipy/optimize/Zeros/bisect.o" failed with exit status 1
```

Any help is very welcomed!!!

Comment: Have you considered installing scipy from [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) as is [suggested in the SciPy website](http://www.scipy.org/install.html#macports)? Or [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)'s package?

Comment: I did. I invoked: sudo port install py27-scipy, but the version that gets installed is still 0.11.0. And I need some functions only available in later version.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sudo  $ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install --upgrade scipy
```

Comment: @LadyBug, what version do you need?

Comment: I need 0.13 or later (maybe v.0.12 would do too, but I can't find its reference guide online to check).

Comment: @LadyBug try `sudo pip install scipy==0.12`